# Android 2.2: ProgressDialog Freezing In Second Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have recently experimented with creating an easy way to open a ProgressDialog up in  a second thread, so if the main thread freezes the dialog will keep working.

Here is the class:
public class ProgressDialogThread extends Thread
{
 public Looper ThreadLooper;
 public Handler mHandler;

public ProgressDialog ThreadDialog;
 public Context DialogContext;
 public String DialogTitle;
 public String DialogMessage;

```
public ProgressDialogThread(Context mContext, String mTitle, String mMessage)
 {
  DialogContext = mContext;
  DialogTitle = mTitle;
  DialogMessage = mMessage;
 }

 public void run()
 {
  Looper.prepare();
  ThreadLooper = Looper.myLooper();

  ThreadDialog = new ProgressDialog(DialogContext);
  ThreadDialog.setTitle(DialogTitle);
  ThreadDialog.setMessage(DialogMessage);
  ThreadDialog.show();

  mHandler = new Handler();

  Looper.loop();
 }

 public void Update(final String mTitle, final String mMessage)
 {
  while(mHandler == null)
   synchronized(this) {
    try { wait(10); } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
     Log.d("Exception(ProgressDialogThread.Update)", e.getMessage() == null ? "MISSING MESSAGE" : e.getMessage());
    }
   }

  mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run() {
    ThreadDialog.setTitle(mTitle);
    ThreadDialog.setMessage(mMessage);
   }});
 }

 public void Dismiss() 
 {
  while(ThreadDialog == null || mHandler == null)
   synchronized(this) {
    try { wait(10); } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
     Log.d("Exception(ProgressDialogThread.Dismiss)", e.getMessage() == null ? "MISSING MESSAGE" : e.getMessage());
    }
   }

  mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run() {
    ThreadDialog.dismiss();
   }});
 }

 public void Continue() 
 {
  while(ThreadLooper == null || mHandler == null)
   synchronized(this) {
    try { wait(10); } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
     Log.d("Exception(ProgressDialogThread.Continue)", e.getMessage() == null ? "MISSING MESSAGE" : e.getMessage());
    }
   }

  mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run() {
    ThreadLooper.quit();
   }});
 }
```

However it sometimes work perfectly but other times the application simply freezes and crashes eventually.

Here is an example of use:

```
ProgressDialogThread thread = new ProgressDialogThread(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
thread.start();
// Do Stuff
thread.Dismiss();
thread.Continue();
```

It generates a lot of warning and even some crashes sometimes:

eg.
 Handler: Sending message to dead thread....

and exceptions like
 ANR in ......
 Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

Thanks for any help,
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When wanting to do stuff in separate threads on Android, you should look at the `AsyncTask` class. You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Googling (or searching here on Stack Overflow) will also give you plenty of information on how to use it it the above link isn't sufficient :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've read that article a few times already =P, however I can not derive from it some way of handling multiple situations where threading is required using a single solution. The other ways I have tried seem to require a fair amount of code spread through multiple files.

Comment: @Alex: I'm not really sure I understand your problem then. See this link for a simple example of how I use `AsyncTask` to show a `ProgressDialog`: http://pastebin.com/tLDYhtj3 (with added comments describing what is going on). If you can explain *why* this doesn't work in your situation, we might be able to further help you.